# Windows services with network access

Tags: windows, service, udp, connection

I have a small server app, which receives `UDP` data on `port X`. When I run this app with a local logged in user account, all is fine and my app receives commands via `UDP`. But when I'm installing the app as a windows service which runs under same local user account, I'm not longer receiving data, when I try to connect from a different machine. Local connections are fine. I've also opened my `UDP port X` in the windows firewall settings, but with no luck.

*Any help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

*Only for the sake of completeness:*
It has been found that it has something to do with the virtual machine in which the Windows runs. I use a network bridge to connect it to my local network. After adding a host-only network adapter, my windows service received all expected commands. *No idea why!?*